# Any realization for Boolean expression builder

Tags: php, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Say I need to create boolean expression builder which consists of predicates (any function returning true/false).

I want to create some builder like chain:

```
$chainA = new Chain(predicateA1());
$chainA->add(AND, predicateX());
$chainB = new Chain(predicateB1());
$chainB->add(AND, predicateX());

$chain = new Chain($chainA);
$chain->add(OR, $chainB);
```

So I'm getting such expression (A1 and X) or (B1 and X), this stuff is pretty simple, but I need one feature - to make some boolean transformation to conjuctive/disjunctive form, for example:

(A1 and X) or (B1 and X) -> (A1 or B1) and X.

I have no idea how to realize this stuff.

Is there any patterns or libraries in php or java solving this problem?

Comment: You could use a binary tree. Left son is for a && and right son for a ||.

Comment: There is a number of tree optimisation tools, but they are usually used in building compilers and are not simple to use.  I know someone who uses LLVM and after 2 years he is pretty confident with it.